# Не запускается BIOS

Tags: bios

Каждый раз когда включал компьютер сбивались настройки даты и времени. Поменял биосу батарейку. Некоторое время работало все хорошо.
Теперь время от времени когда включаю компьютер не могу это сделать так как не запускается даже биос. И только после того как вытащу и поставлю биосу батарейку назад я могу включить компьютер.
Кто-то может что-то посоветовать?
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вин10? Попробуй Биос сбросить

Comment: купите новую батарейку, должно сработать.